# Scroll to bottom in KendoGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid

I want to set scroll' location to bottom in KendoGrid after setting data in DB.
I've tried it like this. but It doesn't work. How can I set focus at Grid' bottom?

```
var grid = $('#divBillGrid').data('kendoGrid');
var content = $(".k-grid-content");
content.scrollTop(grid.tbody.height());
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify the scrolling in dataBound event of the grid

```
dataBound:function(){
    this.content.scrollTop(this.tbody.height())
}
```

Please have a look at the example below

http://jsbin.com/cacokavonu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Hi, @Vivek Parekh. I couldn't check my post last week. sorry about it and appreciate your answer. before I posted this, I also tried dataBound event. but I got an error( Undefined or null , you can not get the reference of 'scrollTop' property. ) How can I solve it?